# How to sort records in python?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, google-cloud-datastore

I am fetching records from table.

This is My class:

```
class user_guide(db.Model):
    ugq_no = db.IntegerProperty()
    ug_quest = db.TextProperty()    
    ug_answer = db.TextProperty()    
    ug_parent_type = db.TextProperty()  
    last_modified_on = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'user_guide'
        verbose_name = 'User Guides'
        verbose_name_plural = 'User Guide'
    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.ugq_no)
```

Following is function.

```
def get_all_record(request):        
    qry_obj = db.Query(user_guide)   
    all_list = []
    #Here I am fetching all records from qry_obj. In this I am getting data in random order.
    for q in qry_obj: 
        all_list.append(q)         
        #all_list.sort()
        sorted(all_list)      

    return HttpResponse(serializers.serialize('json', all_list), mimetype='application/json')
```

In this I am taking all the records from qry_obj and adding those record in all_list.

But I want to sort data in ascending order with respect to **ugq_no** .
I tried sort() and sorted() but no use.
(Django Framwork, python)
Where I am going wrong,please help?

Comment: Have you looked at the django documentation? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#order-by

Comment: This is *not* a django model, looks like google AppEngine or like stuff...

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`.order` method](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queryclass#Query_order) on the query to have the Google datastore sort your records for you:

```
qry_obj = db.Query(user_guide).order('ugq_no')
```

Note that the `user_guide` object *itself* gives you access to the query too:

```
qry_obj = user_guide.all().order('ugq_no')
```

You can turn the query into a list simply by calling `list` on it:

```
all_list = list(qry_obj)
```

Comment: order_by is giving error so I tried with: qry_obj = db.Query(user_guide).order('ugq_no')

Comment: @eegloo: Are you certain you are using Django models here? Looking closer this looks like you are using the Google App Engine instead.

Comment: Yes Google app engine